# Sampling from unknown probability distribution

Tags: bayesian, sampling, monte-carlo, posterior

I'm reading about Monte Carlo methods. Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d $p(x_i|\theta)$, where $\theta$ is an unknown parameter of interest. My textbook states: Suppose we could sample some number $S$ of independent, random $\theta$-values from the posterior $p(\theta|x)$. Then the empirical distribution of the sample $(\theta_1,...,\theta_S)$ would approximate the posterior $p(\theta|x)$.

What does it mean to sample from a probability distribution that is unknown? How is this possible? I would greatly appreciate a simple example.

Comment: It is slightly misleading to say that the probability distribution here is `unknown' - using Bayes' theorem, one can write down a formula for $p  ( \theta | x )$, up to an unknown constant, and so it is at least partially known, in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

In MCMC methods, you typically sample from *partially* known (as also pointed out in the comments section) distributions. Knowing its form up to a scalar (i.e. constant wrt $\theta$) is enough. Therefore, MCMC can also be used to approximate integrals by implicitly calculating the normalization constant. For example, you probably won't be able to calculate the normalization constant for $e^{-\theta^8}$, but will be able to sample from it using MCMC.